# gdal_calc missing arguments?

Tags: gdal

I have been using gdal_calc.py like this:

```
os.system("""gdal_calc.py -a DSM.tif --a_band=1 -b DTM.tif --b_band=1 --calc="a-b" --outfile=CHM.tif""")
```

But now it tells me that I am missing required arguments, which I have in my code.

> gdal_calc.py: error: the following arguments are required: --calc,
> --outfile

Unsure how to fix an error, I don't actually have.

Answer (score 0):

1. In my `gdal_calc.py` version I have to use uppercase letters (..help `gdal_calc.py` ..-A filename  input gdal raster file, you can use any letter (A-Z)).
2. A call direct of the command line from `bash` works without the quotes:

```bsh
    $ gdal_calc.py -A DSM.tif --A_band=1 -B DTM.tif --B_band=1 --calc=A-B --outfile=CHM.tif
    0 .. 10 .. 20 .. 30 .. 40 .. 50 .. 60 .. 70 .. 80 .. 90 .. 100 - Done
```

3. The same way with `ipython` but with correct CLI parameter.

```py
    $ ipython
    python 2.7.17 (default, Feb 27 2021, 15:10:58) 
    Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    
    IPython 5.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
    ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
    %quickref -> Quick reference.
    help      -> Python's own help system.
    object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
    
    In [1]: import os
    
    In [2]: os.system("""gdal_calc.py -A DSM.tif --A_band=1 -B DTM.tif --B_band=1 --calc="A-B" --outfile=CHM.tif""")
    0 .. 10 .. 20 .. 30 .. 40 .. 50 .. 60 .. 70 .. 80 .. 90 .. 100 - Done
    Out[2]: 0
```

### Help `gdal_cal.py`

```bsh
    $ gdal_calc.py --help
    Usage: gdal_calc.py --calc=expression --outfile=out_filename [-A filename]
                        [--A_band=n] [-B...-Z filename] [other_options]
    
    Options:
      -h, --help            show this help message and exit
      --calc=expression     calculation in gdalnumeric syntax using +-/* or any
                            numpy array functions (i.e. log10())
      -A filename           input gdal raster file, you can use any letter (A-Z)
      --A_band=n            number of raster band for file A (default 1)
      --outfile=filename    output file to generate or fill
      --NoDataValue=value   output nodata value (default datatype specific value)
      --type=datatype       output datatype, must be one of ['Int32', 'Int16',
                            'Float64', 'UInt16', 'Byte', 'UInt32', 'Float32']
      --format=gdal_format  GDAL format for output file (default 'GTiff')
      --creation-option=option, --co=option
                            Passes a creation option to the output format driver.
                            Multiple options may be listed. See format specific
                            documentation for legal creation options for each
                            format.
      --allBands=[A-Z]      process all bands of given raster (A-Z)
      --overwrite           overwrite output file if it already exists
      --debug               print debugging information
      --quiet               suppress progress messages
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I did try to use capital letters as well and directly within the command line without quotes. and it still gives me the same error. saying I am missing arguments

Comment: Which gdal version do you use?

Comment: Strange when I search for parts of your error message `grep 'are required' /usr/bin/gdal_calc.py`, I get no hit.

Comment: yes, I even tried using the GUI in QGIS and get similar, yet different error: 'gdal_calc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.. I am using the latest version of gdal 3.4.0. But I also tried with older version 3.3.3

Comment: Can you try from bash `grep 'No ' $(which gdal_calc.py)` and present the output?

Comment: I figured it out. the link between running python files were all over the place. this was just a case of resetting python environments... Thanks for looking into it